# Nginx: readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream

Tags: php, nginx

I have read every other thread about this error with no luck.

I'm running Nginx 1.12.2 with PHP-FPM 5.6 on RHEL 6

I am getting these errors on any/all pages of my site.  It is not related to slow requests. I have witnessed it personally and I immediately get a 500 error page without any waiting.

It affects both POST and GET requests.

I am not running any opcode caches (that I am aware of) I checked all config files, phpinfo() as well as php -v and did not see any mention of opcache or opcode.)

I have turned on catch_workers_output in PHP-FPM. I am not receiving any PHP errors

I have plenty of memory available and there are no errors in the system logs about memory, file descriptors or sockets.

Tried pm_max_requests with both high and low numbers

Not running xdebug plugin

Seems to happen at random times, even in the middle of the night when we aren't very busy at all.

I'm desperate for a solution to this issue which has gone on for months now.

**Here's some of the information asked for in the comments below:**

**Nginx fastcgi.conf (differences from the stock file):**

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
fastcgi_buffer_size   32k;
fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
fastcgi_keep_conn on;
```

**Nginx conf specifics:**

```
sendfile        on;
tcp_nopush      on;
tcp_nodelay     on;
server_tokens   off;
gzip            off;
gzip_static     on;
gzip_comp_level 5;
gzip_min_length 1024;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
client_body_timeout   900;
client_header_timeout 900;
keepalive_timeout     900;
send_timeout          900;
proxy_connect_timeout  900s;
proxy_send_timeout  900s;
proxy_read_timeout  900s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 900s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 900s;
```

**Nginx location specific config:**

```
client_max_body_size 40M;

location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
       include        fastcgi.conf;
}
```

php-fpm config details:

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 1000
pm.start_servers = 300
pm.min_spare_servers = 200
pm.max_spare_servers = 350
pm.max_requests = 1000 ; I've tried higher/lower with no difference
slowlog = /var/log/php-fpm/www-slow.log
catch_workers_output = yes
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php_error_log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path] = /var/lib/php/session
```

Installed Versions:

```
php.x86_64                                                               5.6.33-1.el6.remi                                      @remi-php56                       
php-bcmath.x86_64                                                        5.6.33-1.el6.remi                                      @remi-php56                       
php-cli.x86_64                                                           5.6.33-1.el6.remi                                      @remi-php56                       
php-common.x86_64                                                        5.6.33-1.el6.remi                                      @remi-php56                       
php-devel.x86_64                                                         5.6.33-1.el6.remi                                      @remi-php56                       
php-fedora-autoloader.noarch                                             1.0.0-1.el6.remi                                       @remi                             
php-fpm.x86_64                                                           5.6.33-1.el6.remi                                      @remi-php56                       
php-gd.x86_64                                                            5.6.33-1.el6.remi                                      @remi-php56                       
php-gmp.x86_64                                                           5.6.33-1.el6.remi                                      @remi-php56                       
php-imap.x86_64                                                          5.6.33-1.el6.remi                                      @remi-php56                       
php-mbstring.x86_64                                                      5.6.33-1.el6.remi                                      @remi-php56                       
php-mcrypt.x86_64                                                        5.6.33-1.el6.remi                                      @remi-php56                       
php-mysqlnd.x86_64                                                       5.6.33-1.el6.remi                                      @remi-php56                       
php-pdo.x86_64                                                           5.6.33-1.el6.remi                                      @remi-php56                       
php-pear.noarch                                                          1:1.10.5-4.el6.remi                                    @remi                             
php-pecl-igbinary.x86_64                                                 2.0.5-1.el6.remi.5.6                                   @remi-php56                       
php-pecl-imagick.x86_64                                                  3.4.3-5.el6.remi.5.6                                   @remi-php56                       
php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64                                                    1.3.10-2.el6.remi.5.6                                  @remi-php56                       
php-pecl-jsonc-devel.x86_64                                              1.3.10-2.el6.remi.5.6                                  @remi-php56                       
php-pecl-memcache.x86_64                                                 3.0.8-3.el6.remi.5.6                                   @remi-php56                       
php-pecl-memcached.x86_64                                                2.2.0-3.el6.remi.5.6                                   @remi-php56                       
php-pecl-msgpack.x86_64                                                  0.5.7-1.el6.remi.5.6                                   @remi-php56                       
php-pecl-ssh2.x86_64                                                     0.13-3.el6.remi.5.6                                    @remi-php56                       
php-pecl-zip.x86_64                                                      1.15.2-1.el6.remi.5.6                                  @remi-php56                       
php-process.x86_64                                                       5.6.33-1.el6.remi                                      @remi-php56                       
php-xml.x86_64                                                           5.6.33-1.el6.remi                                      @remi-php56 


nginx version: nginx/1.12.2

Kernel: 2.6.32-696.20.1.el6
```

Comment: Sounds like PHP is seg-faulting. Scan the logs for indication of signals being thrown.

Comment: Nothing showing in the logs.  I see that the logs are working because I do occasionally see calls to undefined functions, etc. - but not nearly at the frequency of the reset-by-peer errors in the Nginx logs.

Comment: Did you check FPM logs in particular?  You have nginx -> fpm daemon -> php interpreter and this error means that the fpm daemon drops the connection with nginx (possibly due to segfault or some other termination).  This is #INSTALL_PREFIX#/log/php-fpm.log which is different from the nginx logs and the PHP error log.  Please post nginx config for FPM.  I'd strongly recommend using tcp instead of unix sockets for proxying to fpm if you aren't already.

Comment: Can you add your detailled version number for PHP? I've already seen issues on RHEL6 with class constant segfaulting fpm. Like this one https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70828 . Not sure it was exactly this bug, they may be others, but removing all `const` usage in our Symfony code was the fix.

Comment: I have posted detailed config information, I'll start grepping through the codebase for uses of CONST.  However, this happens on the simplest pages with no includes and I don't have any opcache enabled, so I doubt that is the issue.

Comment: Try with unix socket, as you have php-fpm and nginx on the same server: ```listen = /var/run/php5.6-fpm.sock``` and for nginx : ```fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5.6-fpm.sock;```

Comment: Are you running out of memory? With `pm.max_children = 1000` and a big `memory_limit` (defaults to 128M) your application may eat over 100GB of memory, if it's exhausted you'd have an error like this. Overnight you may receive a lot of crawlers, which spans too many php-fpm processes and cause this. `pm.max_requests` is the number of requests a single child can respond before it's killed (so you keep **a lot** of open processes most of the time).

I'd suggest always keeping `pm.max_children` * `memory_limit` < available memory.

Comment: For practical purposes, I cannot keep the children * memory limit within bounds.  I'll explain:  A fraction of operations require PHP to stray into a large memory footprint - mostly where customers upload large documents to be parsed.  This is a tiny fraction of my requests, but the memory limit cannot be set on a per-script basis.  We have millions of customers, our servers are very busy, these numbers have been adjusted to accommodate peaks in traffic and work well.  I would be seeing messages in the syslog if a process runs out of memory, and I am not.

Answer (score 1):

In my Case, it because of Netflix Zuul:

I get this message from nginx log when I try to upload file more than 1 MB:

> readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream

My web application uses Nginx and redirects to Netflix Zuul. So I need to set this configuration in properties.yml

```
servlet:
multipart:
  max-request-size: 10MB
  max-file-size: 10MB
```

and it works for me.

Note: if you set the size to 0 and you use spring security it will exceed the limit.